How do you properly secure joists/rim joists atop sill/top plates?
Is there a specific Simpson bracket to attach a rim joist to a sill/top plate or do you simply toe nail it every X" into place?
I have to use joist hangers to attach joists to said rim joist but the joist hangers will essentially rest on the same top plate the rim joist is installed on. I know it will only make the joists slightly proud (2mm+/-) of the rim joist but if there's a special bracket that would lift the rim joist up the thickness of a joist hanger that would be ideal, wouldn't it?
I found the picture below, of similar nature to what I'm describing above, on another stachexchange post where the user is simply using Simpson TA9ZKT staircase angle brackets and I'm guessing (#10 x 1-1/2 in. 1/4-Hex Drive, Strong-Drive SD Connector Screw) screws to secure it.


I think it might come down to your local building codes if you need those ties or just toe nails.  High wind/tornadoes/hurricane areas might require ties.

It might also depend on how much of the joist rests on the top plate.

Nailing the joists in place by driving 3- 3 1/2" nails (16D) will amply hold the joists to the rim joist. The rim joist in all my days have ever only been toenailed with the 16D nails too, every 16". Many times 3 1/4" nails are used (12D) or 3" (10D) too, just more of them.
Edit: I see in the code book they only require 3- 8D (2 1/2") nails in the joist to sill, toenailed. Longer can be used, but the longer nail is more prone to splitting the joist. If 8D nails are used in the rim joist, they are placed every 6". In my opinion, I would use 10D nails
When the sheathing is applied to the outside, it can go over the rim joist and plate, to tie that all together. In my opinion, that picture is way overkill.
Joists, if I remember correctly, only need to bear on a wall 1 1/2" by code. By default, they will bear 2" on a 2X4 wall or 4" on a 2X6 wall. Typically the joists are toenailed to the plate. The nails need to be kept back from the end of the joists to minimize splitting. One from each side.

I am essentially building this floor inside of a box. It's a 10' width, 20' length, 20' height area that has 8' high (2'x4' (nominal)) 16" oc double top plate framing around the perimeter. Each wall has an adjoining room with 15-20' walls. Since I wont have access to the back side of the rim joists, once they are installed to the existing top plates, I cannot nail/screw through them into the joist. In any case I would only be using screws, no nails. Even though there is sufficient space to rest the joists on the top plate I still want to use hangers/rim joists to dist load and for strength

The joists can be toe screwed to the rim joist, and to the plate, but it seems you have made up your mind how you want to do it..... it only a matter of money and time.

I won't be able to apply the subfloor right away and without doing blocking the joist hangers would keep the joists up right while I'm doing all the other stuff from above. Thank you for trying to help me. So to make sure I understand correctly; 2 1/2" screws toe nailed 16" on center is sufficient to attach the rim joist to the top plate?

Yes, come up about an inch up and angle the screws in. Be careful not to let the screws "follow the grain" This is when you start the screws at the proper angle and "something" tries to force the screw at a different angle. It is the screw finding its' way between the soft and hard layers of wood. If  you have a wall plate or a sill plate that everything sets on. you can do the same in the center span before the joists go down. Is this going in a finished room?

Jack, if I were to toenail the 2x10 joist into the rim joist what size screws and how many would I need and on each side?

If I were to do it, I would pilot holes in the joists at about a 30 degree angle, starting roughly an 1 1/2" back from the end. to clarify, the 30 degree is from the joist, not the band so the drill is closer to the joist and not the box sill. This way the shank will fit through the joist and tap directly to the box sill and the joist will not split and the screw will not follow the grain. The screw head will readily draw into the joist and tighten the joist to the box sill very well. 3 screws on side, 2 on the other situated between the 3.  Use 3" screws. 2 1/2" may wok too.
